# UWP setting a ComboBox's SelectedItem when the ItemSource is LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, combobox, uwp

I'm having some trouble getting the SelectedItem to set for a ComboBox when the underlying ItemSource is from a LINQ query.

Here's the code where it sets, the method is coming in from a Cortana voice command. The name of the book when spoken may be different from the written book name because of numbers in the name that I have to spell out, like "first" for example instead of "1".

```
    public void SetBookChapter(string book, int? chapter)
    {
        Model.BookVoiceName voice = dataLoader.BookVoiceNames.FirstOrDefault(b => b.VoiceBookName.ToLower() == book.ToLower());
        if (voice.TotalChapters >= chapter)
        {
            UpdateChapterText = false;
            cmb_Book.SelectedItem = new BookNames { BookName = voice.ActualBookName };
            UpdateChapterText = true;
            cmb_Chapter.SelectedIndex = chapter.Value - 1;
        }
    }
```

When debugging the line for cmb_Book.SelectedItem = ... doesn't set nor does it return any error or information on why, the underlying ItemSource for cmb_Book is set by these properties:

```
    public IEnumerable<BookNames> CurrentBooks
    {
        get
        {
            return from b in dataLoader.Translations[TranslationIndex].Books select new BookNames { BookName = b.BookName };
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<BookNames> BooksInFirstTranslation
    {
        get
        {
            return from b in dataLoader.Translations[0].Books select new BookNames { BookName = b.BookName };
        }
    }
```

Is there a workaround where I can set the SelectedItem directly whenever a LINQ query is used? I thought maybe by using a known type for IEnumerable would help, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equality doesn't work because you're creating different instances of `BookNames` in the items source and in the selected item.

One workaround could be to override the equality comparer of `BookNames`:

```
public class BookNames
{
    public string BookName { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var bookNames = obj as BookNames;

        return bookNames != null && this.BookName.Equals(bookNames.BookName);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.BookName?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    }
}
```

This way, even if `SelectedItem` has a different instance, the ComboBox will be able to match it to another item as long as the name is identical.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it didn't seem to take though. I tried the following:

`BookNames newBook = cmb_Book.Items.Where(b => (b as BookNames).BookName.ToLower() == book.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault() as BookNames;
                cmb_Book.SelectedItem = new BookNames() { BookName = voice.ActualBookName };
                cmb_Book.SelectedItem = newBook;`

Neither of those changed the SelectedItem.

Comment: The hashcodes are also the same between a newly created BookName and pulling the existing item out of cmb_Book.Items, so I'm wondering if it's a ComboBox problem in UWP? I'm not sure of another way to set it, other than doing a loop to iterate through Items, get an index, and set SelectedIndex (which will actually work, but not the most elegant approach).

Comment: What also needed to be done is to convert the IEnumerable<BookNames> over to an ObservableCollection<BookNames> and then it was able to properly set SelectedItem.